# ALTER TABLE CREATE CONSTRAINT IF NOT EXIST possible?

Tags: java, sql, migration, h2, flyway

I have an application which starts (AppStarter) a web server with a web application. The Web Application has migration scripts (flyway).

I want to write some data from AppStarter through JDBC in a table. But I want to create the table if it does not exist. The table also has some constraints.

Within the AppStarter I execute following command:

```
CREATE CACHED TABLE PUBLIC.CORE_USERROLE_TO_PARAMETER (
    ID VARCHAR(32) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    VERSION INTEGER,
    USER_ID VARCHAR(32)NOT NULL,
    ROLE_ID VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    PARAMETER VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.CORE_USERROLE_TO_PARAMETER ADD CONSTRAINT PUBLIC.CURTBP_USER_ID FOREIGN KEY(USER_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.CORE_USER(ID) NOCHECK;
ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.CORE_USERROLE_TO_PARAMETER ADD CONSTRAINT PUBLIC.CURTBP_ROLE_ID FOREIGN KEY(ROLE_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.CORE_USER_ROLE(ID) NOCHECK;
```

The web app also reads some information from this table and creates the tables. 
Now I have a sql migration script

```
CREATE CACHED TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PUBLIC.CORE_USERROLE_TO_PARAMETER (
    ID VARCHAR(32) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    VERSION INTEGER,
    USER_ID VARCHAR(32)NOT NULL,
    ROLE_ID VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    PARAMETER VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);
```

But how do I create the constraint only if they does not already exist?

Thanks in advance

Currently I can get if the constraints exists with

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINTS WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME='CURTRP_USER_ID'
```

but how do I build this into a if query with H2

**Edit:**
I could move the constraint part in total to the migration script, but this seems somehow wrong.

I am working with H2 Database.

Comment: Did you try `IF NOT EXISTS`? The documentation seems to suggest this is possible http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#constraint_name_definition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following my comment, this should be possible:

```
ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.CORE_USERROLE_TO_PARAMETER
  ADD CONSTRAINT IF NOT EXISTS PUBLIC.CURTBP_USER_ID
    FOREIGN KEY(USER_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.CORE_USER(ID) NOCHECK;

ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.CORE_USERROLE_TO_PARAMETER
  ADD CONSTRAINT IF NOT EXISTS PUBLIC.CURTBP_ROLE_ID
    FOREIGN KEY(ROLE_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.CORE_USER_ROLE(ID) NOCHECK;
```

Comment: So obvious, I thought I tried this but apparently I messed up while trying. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this query to get the foreign key constraints
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINTS WHERE CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'REFERENTIAL'

Answer (score -2):

You can try ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS like CREATE IF EXISTS. If its a responsibility of your application only, and not handled by another app or script.

Comment: This is completely unreadable. Please consider using [markdown](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Also use *full stops* (`.`) to mark the end of a sentence.