# Postgres ALTER TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT IF NOT EXISTS not working

Tags: postgresql

I need to add a Constraint `if not exists` and am hitting the following error. Note that a similar `if not exists` for a new Column, right above it, does work. There's some syntax error when adding a Constraint, am I missing something?

```
alter table requests_t
add constraint if not exists 
valid_bias_check CHECK (bias_flag::text = ANY (ARRAY['Y'::character varying::text, 'N'::character varying::text]));
```

Error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "not"
LINE 2: add constraint if not exists
```

[image]

Comment: The answer is simple: [as documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html) there is no option `if not exists` when using `add constraint`

Comment: That's a shame. Any equivalents possible?

Comment: Also, why is the following answer provided (and accepted)? https://stackoverflow.com/a/43755195/1005607

Comment: That question is about H2, not Postgres

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Postgres doesn't support this syntax with constraints (see `a_horse_with_no_name`'s comment), I rewrote it as:

```
alter table requests_t
drop constraint if exists valid_bias_check;

alter table requests_t
add constraint 
valid_bias_check CHECK (bias_flag::text = ANY (ARRAY['Y'::character varying::text, 'N'::character varying::text]));
```